# Error:Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe"

Tags: java, linux, amazon-web-services, jenkins, installation

When i was installing jenkins in AWS instance with java (jdk 1.8.0) observe error
"`Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details."`

when i execute status command we get below error

`[ec2-user@ip-172-31-47-33 ~]$ sudo systemctl status  jenkins.service
● jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Thu 2023-02-09 04:00:53 UTC; 37s ago
Process: 11898 ExecStart=/usr/bin/jenkins (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 11898 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 09 04:00:53 ip-172-31-47-33.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: jenkins.service: main process exited, code=exite...URE
Feb 09 04:00:53 ip-172-31-47-33.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Feb 09 04:00:53 ip-172-31-47-33.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit jenkins.service entered failed state.
Feb 09 04:00:53 ip-172-31-47-33.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: jenkins.service failed.
Feb 09 04:00:53 ip-172-31-47-33.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: jenkins.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 09 04:00:53 ip-172-31-47-33.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Feb 09 04:00:53 ip-172-31-47-33.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for jenkins.service
Feb 09 04:00:53 ip-172-31-47-33.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Feb 09 04:00:53 ip-172-31-47-33.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit jenkins.service entered failed state.
Feb 09 04:00:53 ip-172-31-47-33.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: jenkins.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.`

To resolve this error :

**i follow below steps:
remove previously installed java

- sudo yum remove java*
  install java 11
- sudo amazon-linux-extras install java-openjdk11**